# minimize the matrix 2-norm

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm reading a paper, and encounter some problem:

Given $\left\{x_i\in\mathbb{R}^n\mid i=1,2,\ldots,N \right\}$, and $V\in M(n,p)$ is a matrix. Then what is the $A\in M(p,n)$ which would minimize $\sum_{i=1}^N \|VA(\bar{x}-x_i)\|^2$, where $\bar{x}=(\sum_{i=1}^N x_i)/N$?

Depend on the context, the answer should be $V^T$, but I don't know why. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: No, the answer would be $0$.  Perhaps that's not the question you really meant to ask.

Comment: You're right... But what if I add a condition that $A$ need to be nonzero?

Comment: Then you could fix some $A$ and get some value of the objective function $f(A) \ge 0$. But then $f(cA) = c^2 f(A)$ for any scalar $c$, so taking $c \to 0$ makes the value of the objective function arbitrarily close to zero.